# Не видит импортируемого модуля

Tags: node.js

Всем привет.
Такой вопрос.
Есть код:

```
var request = require("request");

    vk.on("message",function (e, msg) {

        if(/^\!test/.test(msg.body))
        { 
          url = "...";
          request({url: url,json: true}, function (error, response, body) {
            // body
          })
        }

    });
```

Т.е. в шапке файла объявляется подключение к модулю, а далее внутри команд/функций моудль уже используется.
Раньше это работало.
А сейчас почему-то перестало:  работает только в том случае, если `var request = require("request");` прописано после `if(/^\!test/.test(msg.body))`, т.е. непосредственно внутри команды.

С чем связан факт прекращения распознавания `request` непосредственно в шапке?

Я надеюсь, я понятно изложил суть проблемы.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Перестало = какую ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: Никакую, просто не выполняет запрос, будто модуль не объявлен.

Comment: хорошо бы чуть больше кода. В том числе, со строкой подключения vk